# Please help me, how to do his - SQL query (SQL Server 2000)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have data like this:

```
ID   Name         Date
1    kishore      18-jan-2010
2    kishh        19-jan-2010
3    kii          NULL
4    kk           null
5    k            19-jan-2010
```

I should get a result like this:

```
ID   Name           Date
1    kishore        18-jan-2010
2    kishh,kii,kk   19-jan-2010
5    k              19-jan-2010
```

Comment: No, I am a MySQL expert, not SQL-Server-2000 one. Sorry bro, *sniff*.

Comment: thats ok, any way thank you :)

Comment: Is it putting all Names with NULL Date in the Name field of the nearest previous record with Date NOT NULL?

Comment: What are you trying to group on? Or more specifically, why are rows 2-4 grouped together and not row 5?

Comment: it wil have null field only...

Comment: But why are rows 3 & 4 grouped with row 2 and not say #5? I think you need to give more requirements and maybe a reason for doing what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you create a function which takes an ID and returns the string you're after...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StringFromID(@id int)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value varchar(8000)
    DECLARE @date datetime
    SELECT @date = [date], @value = [name] 
    FROM test_data WHERE [id] = @id

    WHILE EXISTS (  SELECT * FROM test_data 
            WHERE [id] = @id + 1 
            AND [date] IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @value = @value + ',' + [name]
        FROM test_data
        WHERE [id] = @id + 1

        SELECT @id = @id + 1
    END
    RETURN @value
END
```

Then you call that function and display your results.

```
SELECT [id], dbo.StringFromID(t.[id]) 'Name', [date]
FROM test_data t
WHERE [date] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, write out the desired sort criteria in addition to example. Try this:

```
select [id], [name], [date] from MyTable
where [date] is not null
order by [date]
```

Comment: But this will loose Names from records with NULL Date. I think it's a bit more complicated.. maybe it needs a procedure.